# I have two lamp post lights, wired in line. No dusk/dawn eye. The first post light lights. The second does not

Tags: wiring, post, light

There is power to the second post light. There is also power in the light socket itself. I've checked the ground at both lights and they appear to be working fine.  What could be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried changing the bulb?

Comment: Did you wire them in series?

Comment: Is the second lamp daisy chained from the first? I found this in one case where the wiring to the 2nd lamp was controlled by the first with 2 dusk to dawn fixtures the second one would not work but did have power but it was modified by the first and not a sine wave so the electronics in the 2nd unit did not work, finally figured it out by putting a oscope on the line and observing the power.

Comment: I have tried changing the bulb. Also tried going with LED for less draw. Didn't work. I am not sure how the posts were wired as I did not install them. Not sure if in series or not. What I do know is that the wiring comes directly from the switch in house to the first post. . . from there I have no idea how the connection was made to go to the second post. That wiring is underground crossing from one side of the driveway to the other.

Comment: When the first light comes on, it could be “telling” the second light that it’s still daylight. How close together are they?

Comment: Voting to close. Wiring details are required and OP hasn't been back.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have power to ground on both the hot wire and the neutral wire at the lamp socket? If you do, you have a broken neutral between the light and the neutral of the first light. If you have power across the hot and neutral (usually black and white wires) then change the bulb as mmathis said. By the way neutral and ground are not the same at the appliance.